# Grafana AAD Authentication - login.OAuthLogin(missing saved state)

Tags: grafana

I have an issue with login via AAD authentication.

I have iframe where is panel and the iframe is inside a web page with a user authenticated against AAD.

When the iframe opens it redirects me to the login page:

[image]

(it is supposed that we are authenticated but ...)

And if I press Sign in with Microsft, I get the error:

[image]

In grafana's logs I see:

```
t=2021-07-06T15:06:36+0000 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/login/azuread status=302 remote_addr=**XX.XX.181.X** time_ms=0 size=400 referer=https://**mydomain**.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:3000/login
t=2021-07-06T15:06:39+0000 lvl=eror msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/login/azuread status=500 remote_addr=**XX.XX.181.X** time_ms=0 size=1743 referer=https://login.microsoftonline.com/
```

But I don't know which is the problem ... any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a problem with same site cookie config. Try `GF_SECURITY_COOKIE_SAMESITE=none` (but I don't guarantee that's a solution, because you didn't provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, your browser console may give you ideas what's blocked and why)

Generally: Grafana in the iframe is (will be) a problem, because browsers limit (or will limit in near future) this kind of access - see recent 2021 `Chrome’s SameSite cookie update`. Safari is also very strict in this limitation. So you may solve it, but some browser may still have this problem or may have this problem soon.

Comment: Ok, I solved the error configuring cookie_samesite = true in grafana.ini and this solves the error, then I added disable_login_form = true and oauth_auto_login = true and now seems that works,

Answer (score 0):

```js
services:
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    pid : 
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

    volumes:
      - C:\Users\suraj.kalloli\grafana\keycloak.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    command:
      - start-dev
      - --import-realm
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
    volumes:
      - ./keycloak-config/:/opt/keycloak/data/import/
```

```html
[auth.generic_oauth]
name = OAuth login
icon = signin
enabled = true
scopes = openid 
client_id = grafanatest
client_secret = 90z3ONKTTDSB9scsIevXebC2Ek6O6Ue8
use_pkce = false
allow_sign_up = true
auth_url = http://host.docker.internal:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth
token_url = http://host.docker.internal:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
api_url = http://host.docker.internal:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
login_attribute_path = preferred_username
role_attribute_path: "contains(realm_access.roles[*], 'Admin') && 'Admin' || contains(realm_access.roles[*], 'Editor') && 'Editor' || 'Editor'"
role_attribute_strict = true
[paths]
data = /var/lib/grafana/
logs = /var/log/grafana
plugins = /var/lib/grafana/plugins
provisioning = /etc/grafana/provisioning
[plugins]
allow_loading_unsigned_plugins = camptocamp-prometheus-alertmanager-datasource
#log level
[log.file]
level = debug
```

-Add valid mapper to the client and make email verify ON for the user with respect to email,if you given scope as openid email or openid,
-Mention Firstname and lastname to the user in keycloak so grafana can take the assigned names.

-First snippet is docker compose file
-Second one keycloak.ini file